# Can we lobby stackexchange to support "&" as a valid tag character?

Tags: feature-request, tags

It feels to me like over half of the questions on the site are tagged [dd*]. Yes, it works acceptably, and is probably the best solution for now. It also looks unreadable and silly.

Comment: FWIW, there is an open [feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/71106/156625) to allow additional characters in tags, although the ampersand is not specifically listed as part of the request.

Comment: It's not just D&D that would benefit, but also M&M (Mutants & Masterminds), T&T (Tunnels & Trolls), C&C (Castles & Crusades), and a few minor ones, especially if we start diversifying into tags like `M&M-3e`.

Answer (score 4):

No.  It is not permitted because of the way the sites are built.  URL special characters like /, & and # are not allowed because tags and handles and titles show up in the URLs to make the site work.  For instance, look at the tagging or feature-request links on the right sidebar.  The system dynamically builds a URL that includes those tags to let you search.

I like DnD.

Comment: I appreciate that not permitting them in tags, etc., *simplifies* the site code, but [escaping the ampersand](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=escape+ampersand+url) is a solvable problem so it's not flat-out impossible. It may well be more work than is justified for a niche feature request, but exploring that would be part of the lobbying give-and-take.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so; if we really don't want to use [dd] we can use [dnd] and it works just as well.

When they release an "Ampersands and Octothorpes" module, I think we'll have a case... but until then...

Comment: I agree, especially since there's an underlying technical issue (`&` is a special character in url's)

Comment: I prefer dnd as well.